# Can only write to first element of char** buffer

Tags: c, pointers, split

I'm quite new to C and am trying to write a function, which will split a string into an array of strings at a specific delimiter. But strangely I can only write at the first index of my `char**` array of strings, which will be my result. For example if I want to split the following string `"Hello;;world;;!"` at `;;` I get `[ "Hello" ]` instead of `[ "Hello", "world", "!" ]`. I can't find my mistake.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "strings.h"

int split(char **dest, const char *src, const char *splitStr) {
    char buffer[16384];
    int counter = 0;
    int len = strlen(splitStr);
    int flag = 0;
    int start = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(src); i++) {
        flag = 0;
        if (src[i] == splitStr[0]) {
            for (int j = 1; j < len; j++) {
                //check if all elements in delimiter are in string
                if (src[i + j] == splitStr[j] && j != (len - 1)) {
                    continue;
                }
                else if(src[i + j] == splitStr[j] && j == (len - 1)) {
                    buffer[i] = '\0';
                    dest[counter] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (i - start + 1));
                    strncpy(dest[counter], buffer + start, (i - start));
                    start = i + (len-1)
                    flag = 1;
                    i += (len - 1);
                    counter++;
                }
                //if not break
                else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    
        if (i == (strlen(src) - 1)) {
            buffer[i] = src[i];
            buffer[i + 1] = '\0';
            counter++;
            break;
        }
        if (flag == 0) {
            buffer[i] = src[i];
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

A proper function call would look like this:

```
auto src = "Hello;;world;;!";
auto buffer = (char **)malloc(32);
int count = split(buffer, src, ";;");
```

The buffer should contain, all the splitted strings, more or less like this: `[ "Hello", "world", "!" ]`.
Currently my result buffer looks like this in the debugger. It appears as only the first element is written into it.
[image: Debugging result of buffer after function call]

Comment: Do yourself a favor and apply proper formatting to your code. The inconsistent indentation makes it really hard to read.

Comment: How do you call this? Especially: how is the data that `dest` points at allocated?

Comment: please give a [mre]

Comment: What is the role of `start`? You never change it. Also, besides adding how you call your function as requested by Lundin also show how you print the results afterwards.

Comment: I added some more info, I willl read into how to make a minimal reproducile example

Comment: @Gerhardh yes there's a mistake.  write all the nin-delimiter characters in the temp buffer I made in the dunction. Then I copy them to dest. Since  don't want to copy the wole buffer everytime I add a new substring I mark the start of the new substring as start. I will correct it.

Comment: Your debugger does not know how many elements are accessible via your pointer and therefore only shows one. That is only a problem of displaying your data in the debugger. Try to print the content in your program. But also your memory for `dest` is not very useful. Where do you get `32` bytes from? Do you assume 4 or 8 bytes per pointer and 8 or 4 pointers to store?

Comment: First, your interface makes little sense. Why do you make the caller allocate a part of the memory and `split` allocate another part of the memory? Second, separate your huge function to more manageable parts. How about writing a function that finds the first occurrence of `splitStr` in `src`?

Comment: T.Naz, `strncpy(dest[counter], buffer + start, (i - start));` risks not forming a _string_.  Do not use `strncpy()`.  Please example your goal with this line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you compute string lengths repeatedly, which may be very inefficient. Instead of testing `i < strlen(src)` you should write `src[i] != '\0'`.
- your test for check a matching delimiter is too complicated. You should use `strstr` to locate the delimiter string in the remaining portion of the string.
- `strncpy` does not do what you think: `strncpy(dest[counter], buffer + start, (i - start));` should be replaced with `memcpy(dest[counter], buffer + start, i - start);` and you must set the null terminator explicitly: `dest[counter][i - start] = '\0';` You should read [why you should never use `strncpy()`](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/).
- it is unclear why you use `buffer` at all.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* if POSIX function strndup() is not defined on your system, use this */
char *strndup(const char *str, size_t n) {
    size_t len;
    for (len = 0; len < n && str[len] != '\0'; len++)
        continue;
    char *s = malloc(len + 1);
    if (s != NULL) {
        memcpy(s, str, len);
        s[len] = '\0';
    }
    return s;
}

int split(char **dest, const char *src, const char *splitStr) {
    const char *p = str;
    const char *end;
    int counter = 0;
    size_t len = strlen(splitStr);
    if (len == 0) {
        /* special case */
        while (*p != '\0') {
            dest[counter++] = strndup(p++, 1);
        }
    } else {
        while ((end = strstr(p, splitStr)) != NULL) {
            dest[counter++] = strndup(p, end - p);
            p = end + len;
        }
        dest[counter++] = strdup(p);
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are not updating the start variable after you have copied the first string.

For simple debugging I would recommend adding some printf statements to see what is going on.

Proper formatting is not to be underestimated to make the code easy to read and easier to debug.

Also it is not clear what the buffer is for, and I think you can do without it.

The tips in the comments are also good. Split the function into smaller pieces and structure your code so it is simple to read.

A suggestion is to write a function to find the index of the next split string and the end of the string. Then you can use that to get the index and length you need to copy.